# Ionic +Firestore - bollean field Retrieving

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I need to Retrieving the value of the a **Boolean** of the Document FIRESTORE

[image]

does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you can try this:

**Using** `Cloud Firestore SDK`.

```
let docRef = db.collection("following").doc("your-id");

docRef.get().then((doc)=> {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        let myData=doc.data();
        let isTrue= myData.boolean-property-name;//return true or false
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

**Using AngularFire2:** [**Docs**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs/firestore)

**Note:**

Read this article: [**Google Cloud Firestore integration with Ionic and AngularFire**](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-firestore-integration-with-ionic-and-angularfire-41122af71433)

`your-id` - You need to pass your `doc` here

`boolean-property-name` - This is just a dummy name. You need to pass your actual property name here. On your case its like `cug.....`

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer ... I tried with the indicated code, however it returned 3 errors, the Print is in the link: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B14jg18TLF3USC1xc292S3FYR0k)

Comment: I made the change now I only get 1 error:

**Typescript Error
Property 'get' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreDocument <{}>'.**

Comment: Are you using `angularfire2`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `angularfire2`

Comment: Oh.. You need to provide more code on your question. I just use firebase SDK. Anyway: You need to read this : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs/firestore

Comment: ok ... I will check the documentation on the link, I believe that now it is easier to solve the problem ... you helped me a lot with the code that sent me ... thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Firestore does not support direct .get anymore, use doc.ref.get() instead.